# Animate an image in Qt

Tags: image, qt, animation

I have added an .png image to my QGraphics scene using addPixmap() . Now I want to animate that image. Means I want to move that image & it will be replaced with a new image. Replace the old with new one show that it will look like moving.

Comment: What do you mean by "moving"? Moving around in your window or a moving image like a *.gif?

Comment: as a .gif ... & I also want to move that around the window also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addPixmap() will return a QGraphicsPixmapItem which you can move with setPos(). You can also change the pixmap with setPixmap().

You can do the animation manually using a timer to update the position and pixmap (with QTimer). There is a new animation framework in recent Qt releases which is documented here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/animation-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

For me, I added into **QLabel** and moved it by **QTimer** on parent **QWidget**.

Comment: i am making a game ...N I dont think this is a nice idea to implement that.